# How do I find how much SVN traffic I'm using?

Tags: svn, networking, monitoring, traffic

At my office we have an SVN server set up and I'd like to know how much traffic it is using. I'm not interested in the bandwidth, just the total number of 1s and 0s the SVN service is sending/receiving.

The data will all be going via the `svn://` protocol, and the server is running XP pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start | My Computer - right click Manage

Computer Management - Performance Logs & Alerts.

Add a new log, set it up to monitor the SVN  process once a day.  Select the "I/O Other Bytes/sec" as the counter to record.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just monitor the SVN server process using task manager, and add the "I/O Other Bytes" column?

Otherwise, [Sysinternal's Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can certainly do this.

Comment: that's excellent, thanks. Do you know if there's a way to track this over time? eg: 100MB on monday, 283MB on tuesday...?